# my CLR visual c++ forms went blank after editing it for days

Tags: visual-studio, clr

i'm new to visual studio CLR C++
recently started working on a project and after few days editing a form it went blank,
i can see all objects in the .h file
but can't see them on the design file
[image]

tried to google it, but can't find any solution
and can't find any form setting that can affect it.

Comment: I understand the frustration, this is one more reason to use source control, this issue might be related: [Form Design view goes blank](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/form-design-view-goes-blank/287062)

Answer (score 0):

ok, so in my case i declared InitializeComponent in the form .h file
as void InitializeComponent(Exam^ exam)
Exam is a class i created
,when i rolled back it to (void InitializeComponent(void)) the problem was solved

looks like visual studio can't show objects in design view when InitializeComponent()
conatain Uinitialized varebles.

thanks for everyone.